# Как привязать контекст this в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

TypeScript ругается на метод isReviewLongEnough, не нравится ему this.
Ниже два варианта одного и того же метода со стрелочной функцией и с декларативной функцией.

Стрелочная функция:

```
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
  rating: 0,
  review: '',
  isReviewLongEnough: (): boolean => {
    const reviewLength = this.review.trim().length;
    return reviewLength >= MIN_REVIEW_SIMBOLS && reviewLength <= MAX_REVIEW_SIMBOLS;
  }
});
```

Обычная функция:

```
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
   rating: 0,
   review: '',
   isReviewLongEnough(): boolean {
     const reviewLength = this.review.trim().length;
     return reviewLength >= MIN_REVIEW_SIMBOLS && reviewLength <= MAX_REVIEW_SIMBOLS;
   }
});
```

Я так понял что проблема в том что у **this** - тип **any**. Т.к. я только первую неделю изучаю тупСкрип и реакт, я не могу даже понять какой использовать синтаксис, чтобы правильно обозначить тип у **this**

Comment: `function(this: SomeType)`

Comment: Первая очевидно неверна вообще. Вторая зависит от того как вызывается функция isReviewLongEnough. Я бы сказал что неплохо бы узнать в чём же состоит разница между стрелочной и обычной функцией.

Comment: Отдельный вопрос, зачем вообще в state класть функцию…

Comment: @AlexeyTen стрелочная получает контекст в момент создания, обычная в момент вызова, если я не ошибаюсь. Но когда я использую тупСкрип я не совсем понимаю какие знания из JS применимы в том или ином случае. Тупскрип сильно запутывает, не знаю что мне можно делать, а что нельзя.

Comment: `const isReviewLongEnough = (): boolean {}; ... useState({ isReviewLongEnough })`

Comment: @AlexeyTen я сразу хочу валидировать длину комментария. Я думал в стейт можно класть всё что угодно. Мне нужно чтобы каждый раз когда в поле textarea вбивается текст, метод isReviewLongEnough автоматически дисэйблил кнопку Submit пока текст комментария не окажется в диапазоне 50-300 символов.

Comment: В state кладут *изменяемое* состояние. Функция проверки длины *не меняется*, так что никакого смысла класть её в state нет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen понял, спасибо за совет. Сейчас тогда выдерну этот метод из стейта и сделаю отдельную функцию. Но думаю проблема с контекстом this всё равно отстанется. Сейчас поэкспериментирую...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не могу себе представить причину зачем бы в `state` класть функцию.
Так что нужно просто вытащить её из `state` и вообще не заморачиваться с `this`.

```js
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
  rating: 0,
  review: ''
});

const isReviewLongEnough: (): boolean => {
    const reviewLength = formState.review.trim().length;
    return reviewLength >= MIN_REVIEW_SIMBOLS && reviewLength <= MAX_REVIEW_SIMBOLS;
  }
};
```

Comment: по красоте `formState.review?.trim().length ?? 0` или `(formState.review ?? '').trim().length`

Comment: Я уже вытащил функцию из стейта. Но почему-то она не вызывается, когда Реакт перерисовывает компонент.

Comment: Я тупень, не правильно написал сам код функции, нужно было инвертировать булево значение, которое возвращает функция. Теперь всё работает. Всем спасибо, за помощь и советы. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: @nörbörnën ну если кто-то в стейт забудет положить строку, то сам себе злобный буратино =)

Comment: @nörbörnën на вот этот код - `formState.review ?? '').trim().length`, - почему-то вылезает ошибка.
С другой стороны не совсем понял, зачем нужен оператор нулевого слияния, если у меня в стейте в уже есть поле `review: ''`?
`formState.review.trim().length;` - сейчас возвращает ноль, даже если я ничего не записываю в это поле стейта.

Comment: телепатически я с ошибками не умею. "зачем" - затем что никто из нас не знает как заполняется `formState.review`, а значит в ней может быть undefined или null